# FullCalendar - Only request events for current month

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, fullcalendar

My database has many events, so I'd only like to request events for the current month that the user is on to make load time faster.

The events are loaded from a php script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#fullcalendar').fullCalendar({
        navLinks: true,
        editable: true,
        eventLimit: true, 
        defaultTimedEventDuration: '00:15:00',
        events: '<?php echo $cal_root;?>/_calendar/load_calendar.php?month_and_year=',  
    });

});
```

So I need to pass the month and year that the user is on to the php script to request the relevant events for that month, is there a way this can be done?

Comment: Which library are you using to render the calendar?

Comment: Do you mean jquery?

Comment: No I mean if you are using this library >> [Full Calendar JQuery](https://fullcalendar.io/)

Comment: Yep that's the one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just discovered that start and end variables are sent automatically when requesting the events via ajax.

So I didn't have to add anything to the Fullcalendar code, I just had to pick up those variables with my PHP script, e.g. `$_GET['start']` and `$_GET['end']`

Comment: can you be more specific on how to make this?

Comment: You use this in the php script which the jquery calls to fetch the events. The start and end date are already automatically going to be available in that script as those $_GET values. My events are in a mySQL database, so I then used those values in SQL to fetch only events within the date range.

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem. I suggest this [method](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/viewRender/).
As the document says:

> This callback will get triggered when the user changes the view, or **when** any of the date **navigation methods are called**. This callback will trigger after the view has been fully rendered, but before events have been rendered (see also: eventAfterAllRender).

So method is call after the first render, and every render when the navigation is called (change the week or change the view). From the [view object](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/views/View_Object/) you can get the start and the end visible day, so you can get the events from your DB dynamically.

It helped me, I hope it helps you as well. :)

Comment: It turns out the calendar sends the start and end date automatically whenever it requests the events via ajax, so I just had to use $_GET['start'] and $_GET['end'] from my php script